# Possible explanations for loss increasing?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, tensorboard, cross-entropy

I've got a 40k image dataset of images from four different countries.  The images contain diverse subjects: outdoor scenes, city scenes, menus, etc.  I wanted to use deep learning to geotag images.

I started with a small network of 3 conv->relu->pool layers and then added 3 more to deepen the network since the learning task is not straightforward.

My loss is doing this (with both the 3 and 6 layer networks):[image]:

The loss actually starts kind of smooth and declines for a few hundred steps, but then starts creeping up.

**What are the possible explanations for my loss increasing like this?**

My initial learning rate is set very low: 1e-6, but I've tried 1e-3|4|5 as well.  I have sanity-checked the network design on a tiny-dataset of two classes with class-distinct subject matter and the loss continually declines as desired.  Train accuracy hovers at ~40%

Answer (score 8):

I would normally say your learning rate it too high however it looks like you have ruled that out.  You should check the magnitude of the numbers coming into and out of the layers.  You can use tf.Print to do so.  Maybe you are somehow inputting a black image by accident or you can find the layer where the numbers go crazy.

Also how are you calculating the cross entropy?  You might want to add a small epsilon inside of the log since it's value will go to infinity as its input approaches zero.  Or better yet use the `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(...)` function which takes care of numerical stability for you.

Since the cost is so high for your crossentropy it sounds like the network is outputting almost all zeros (or values close to zero).  Since you did not post any code I can not say why.  I think you may just be zeroing something out in the cost function calculation by accident.

Comment: I am using `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(...)` FYI.

Comment: I figured you might be.  Otherwise the cost would have gone to infinity and you would get a nan.  The output is definitely going all zero for some reason.  Maybe try using the elu activation instead of relu since these do not die at zero.

Comment: I'm using `tf.nn.elu`s in my conv layers and relu in the final hidden layer: `hidden = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, fc1_weights) + fc1_biases)`.  Perhaps I can try a elu there too.

Comment: You don't need an activation in the final layer since the softmax function is an activation.  Also make sure your weights are initialized with both positive and negative values.

Comment: It's even a bit stronger - you absolutely do not want relus in the final layer, you **want** the logits to be able to go to arbitrary negative values.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the problem ,I was using keras library (tensorflow backend)

```
    Epoch 00034: saving model to /home/ubuntu/temp/trained_data1/final_dev/final_weights-improvement-34-0.627.hdf50
Epoch 35/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 65s 287us/step - loss: 0.2870 - acc: 0.9331 - val_loss: 2.7904 - val_acc: 0.6193
Epoch 36/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 65s 288us/step - loss: 0.2813 - acc: 0.9331 - val_loss: 2.7907 - val_acc: 0.6268

Epoch 00036: saving model to /home/ubuntu/temp/trained_data1/final_dev/final_weights-improvement-36-0.627.hdf50
Epoch 37/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 65s 286us/step - loss: 0.2910 - acc: 0.9330 - val_loss: 2.5704 - val_acc: 0.6327
Epoch 38/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 65s 287us/step - loss: 0.2982 - acc: 0.9321 - val_loss: 2.5147 - val_acc: 0.6415

Epoch 00038: saving model to /home/ubuntu/temp/trained_data1/final_dev/final_weights-improvement-38-0.642.hdf50
Epoch 39/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 68s 301us/step - loss: 0.2968 - acc: 0.9318 - val_loss: 2.7375 - val_acc: 0.6409
Epoch 40/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 68s 299us/step - loss: 0.3124 - acc: 0.9298 - val_loss: 2.8359 - val_acc: 0.6047

Epoch 00040: saving model to /home/ubuntu/temp/trained_data1/final_dev/final_weights-improvement-40-0.605.hdf50
Epoch 41/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 65s 287us/step - loss: 0.2945 - acc: 0.9315 - val_loss: 3.5825 - val_acc: 0.5321
Epoch 42/150
226160/226160 [==============================] - 65s 287us/step - loss: 0.3214 - acc: 0.9278 - val_loss: 2.5816 - val_acc: 0.6444
```

When i saw my model ,the model was consisting of too many neurons ,
In short the model was overfitting.
I decreased the no of neurons in 2 dense layers (from 300 neurons to 200 neurons)

Comment: Overfitting does not make the training loss increase, rather, it refers to the situation where training loss decreases to a small value while the validation loss remains high.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful for somebody out there who is facing similar issues to the above. OP is using Tensorflow, in which case this is irrelevant and not the answer, but if you ever implement neural networks and backpropagation by hand (for example for coursework or assignments) make sure that you are *subtracting* the gradient from the parameters and not adding it. Easy mistake to make - adding the gradient will move away from the nearest minimum and thus increase the loss. I had this very problem only about 30 minutes before writing this.