# Why is the loss error increasing? Error backpropagation algorithm

Tags: python, neural-network

I implemented it according to the formula of error backpropagation method. Is there any problem

```
import numpy as np
# 定义神经网络的参数
# 输入层3个，隐藏层4个，输出层1个
W2 = np.random.randn(4, 3)  # 第二层权重矩阵
B2 = np.random.randn(4, 1)  # 第二层的偏置
W3 = np.random.randn(1, 4)  # 第三层权重矩阵
B3 = np.random.randn(1, 1)


# 定义激活函数sigmoid函数
def sigmoid(X):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-X))


def sigmoid_derivative(X):
    return sigmoid(X) * (1 - sigmoid(X))


# 定义神经网络的前向传播函数
def forward(X):
    # 第2层
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, X) + np.tile(B2, (1, X.shape[1]))
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)
    # 第3层
    Z3 = np.dot(W3, A2) + np.tile(B3, (1, X.shape[1]))
    A3 = sigmoid(Z3)
    return A3


# 定义损失值
def loss(y, y_hat):
    m = len(y)
    return np.sum((y - y_hat) ** 2) / (2 * m)


# 定义损失函数的偏导数
def loss_derivative(y, y_hat):
    return y - y_hat


# 定义反向传播函数
def backward(X, y, y_hat):
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, X)  # m * 100
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)  # m * 100
    Z3 = np.dot(W3, A2)  # k * 100

    # 第3层, J(a)*g(z3)
    delta3 = (y - y_hat) * sigmoid_derivative(Z3)  # k * 100
    # 第2层, (δ2=(W3.T)*δ3)**g(z2)
    delta2 = np.dot(W3.T, delta3) * sigmoid_derivative(Z2)  # m * 100

    # 第3层, dw3=δ3*(a2.T), db3=δ3
    dW3 = np.dot(delta3, A2.T)
    db3 = np.sum(delta3, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    # 第2层, dw2=δ2*(a1.T), db2=δ2
    dW2 = np.dot(delta2, X.T)
    db2 = np.sum(delta2, axis=1, keepdims=True)

    return dW3, dW2, db3, db2


# 定义sigmoid函数的导数
def sigmoid_grad(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))


# 训练数据
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]])
y = np.array([[0], [0], [1], [1], [1]])

# 定义学习率
learning_rate = 0.1

# 训练神经网络
iteratorNum = 10 * 100
J_history = np.zeros(iteratorNum)
for i in range(iteratorNum):
    # 前向传播
    y_hat = forward(X.T)
    # 计算损失函数
    J_history[i] = loss(y, y_hat)
    # 反向传播
    dW3, dW2, dB3, dB2 = backward(X.T, y.T, y_hat)
    # 更新参数
    W3 -= learning_rate * dW3
    B3 -= learning_rate * dB3
    W2 -= learning_rate * dW2
    B2 -= learning_rate * dB2

print(J_history)
case1 = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0]])
print(forward(case1.T))
```

the end loss is 0.99999444. the error loss because biger. what is the reason

[0.99999401 0.99999403 0.99999404 0.99999406 0.99999408 0.99999409
0.99999411 0.99999413 0.99999414 0.99999416 0.99999417 0.99999419
0.99999421 0.99999422 0.99999424 0.99999425 0.99999427 0.99999428
0.9999943  0.99999432 0.99999433 0.99999435 0.99999436 0.99999438
0.99999439 0.99999441 0.99999442 0.99999444]

the res is [[0.9999975  0.99999866]]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible explanations for loss increasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868939/possible-explanations-for-loss-increasing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the deltas with a *learning rate* such as 0.01 when you update the parameters of model. See related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868939/possible-explanations-for-loss-increasing).

Comment: i did, the learning_rate is the learning rate